How to delete additional EFI (EFI NO NAME), for installing Fedora using T2Linux?
I am trying to dual boot Macbook Pro 2019 with Intel & T2 using https://t2linux.org by installing Linux/ Fedora.
Now, the system is NOT booting to live ISO USB.
**me@mes-MacBook-Pro ~ % diskutil list

/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):

   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0

   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1

   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         250.2 GB   disk0s2

   3:                        EFI NO NAME                 999.3 MB   disk0s3

   4:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         749.0 GB   disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):

   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +749.0 GB   disk1

Physical Store disk0s4

   1:                APFS Volume Fedora                  782.3 KB   disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):

   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.2 GB   disk2

Physical Store disk0s2

   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            9.3 GB     disk2s1

   2:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 9.3 GB     disk2s1s1

   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 3.8 GB     disk2s2

   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                2.3 GB     disk2s3

   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     8.5 GB     disk2s4

   6:                APFS Volume VM                      20.5 KB    disk2s6**


Hoe did you make the USB installer/live? The title seems nonsensical.

It seems a duplicate of this one: Why is Macbook Pro 2019 with Intel & T2 NOT recognizing live USB for dual booting Linux using T2Linux ISO image?
